# CondaSSLError -- Installing Environments using Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install environments using Anaconda on my home windows 64 bit computer and am running into this below error message.

[image]

Reviewing previous posts I saw options like the addition of the below code to turn off SSL requirements

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

I'm not interested in this approach as I know it provides a necessary layer of protection on my machine.

Also, found the below option that did not work.

copying these files from Anaconda3/Library/bin to Anaconda3/DLLs :

libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

libssl-1_1-x64.dll

any help in solving the issue or providing a work around to get me install environments.